# Sharing/tethering 3G connection between Android devices

Tags: 2.1-eclair, 3g, wifi-tethering, 4.3-jelly-bean, bluetooth-tethering

Is it possible to share 3G connection between two Android devices, a smartphone with 3G and a tablet with only wi-fi, for me to access the web with the tablet anywhere?

I have a Sony Xperia X8 with 3G connection, but my Nexus 7 doesn't, so I'm kind of tied to places with wi-fi routers, but I thought on using the phone to share connection with the tablet. I already do it with my notebook, although I need the cable.

Phone runs Android 2.1 and tablet runs 4.3, but I may try to install a modded ROM on the phone to update it to 2.3, if needed.

Comment: If you can upgrade the OS on your phone to at least Gingerbread, it will have a built-in hotspot feature you can use via WiFi. Otherwise you might have to root your device, or check the Playstore for solutions not requiring root. Understand that Eclair (2.1) is pretty outdated, so support might be limited.

Comment: Yes, I do understand Eclair is kinda old :/ I will search for a updated ROM for now

Comment: You phone has good development scene over at [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=849). [Latest I could spot is Mini CM10.1 with Android 4.1.2 which does Wi-Fi tethering natively](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1836116).

Good luck.

Comment: @k1chy can you give me directions on how to change ROMs? I failed miserably last try :(

Comment: read the [guide over here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=921652). First you need to Unlock and install a custom recovery like ClockworkMod (CWM). From there it is simple.

Read the instructions clearly and be sure of what you are doing before doing it. Good luck